# Multple Virtual PCs on a Laptop

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtual-machines, virtualization

I have two Virtual PC images on my desktop. I need the VMs to be able to communicate with each other because I intend to use them to try out SQL Server Replication. I have configured both VMs to have 2 network adapters. This 1st adapter is set to use the host laptop's ethernet card and DHCP. The 2nd adapter is configured as "Local only" with an IP address of 192.168.200.1 (VM1) and 192.168.200.2 (VM2).

I found that I was getting lots of error messages about conflicts with the 1st adapter on each machine enabled, so I disabled this in the 2nd VM. I have the firewall disabled on both VMs. Both VMs are running windows server 2003 standard. VM1 is the domain controller (or the 2003 equivalent) and VM2 has been successfully added to the same domain.

Problem: I am able to ping VM2 from VM1 but not VM1 from VM2.

Any ideas what may be blocking?

Thanks

Rob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a routing issue. Could you please post the output of route print for all three machines (host and both VM), as well as more detail about the IP configuration of all interfaces involved.